# Cann't open ftps directory, ftplib.error_perm: 534 Policy requires SSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftps

my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import sys, os

destdir="/dir/"

ftps = FTP_TLS('ftps.website.com')
ftps.set_debuglevel(1)
ftps.set_pasv(False)
ftps.connect(port=21, timeout=80)
ftps.login('login', 'pass')
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.ccc()
ftps.cwd(destdir)
ftps.pwd()
ftps.retrlines('LIST')
ftps.close()
```

Error:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 534 Policy requires SSL.
```

System

```
File transfer protocol = FTP
Cryptographic protocol = TLS/SSL Explicit encryption, TLSv1.2
Encryption algorithm = TLSv1/SSLv3
```

So does anyone know what to do in order to connect to ftps server ? 
Thanks

Comment: Please guys, at least in which direction should i go ? very need